# When are correlation coefficients and variances not enough?

Tags: probability, correlation, variance

I am reading a paper and found the following,

> Statistical uncertainties and dependencies are often measured by variances and correlation coefficients, but both uncertainty and dependence can be defined purely in terms of probabilities $(p_i)$, without considering the actual state of system.

Now I am leaving the context out of the question for it allows me to ask a general question.

1. When are correlation coefficients and variances not enough? Is there a X which we can not predict from these two but can from probability?
2. Though the paper does not imply but I suspect that while working with correlation coefficients and variances, one needs to know the actual state of system to claim some X. On the other hand, same X can be claimed without knowing the actual state of system if only one works with probabilities $(p_i)$.

PS: I am new to statistics.

Comment: It's unclear which "probability" you mean in "we can not predict from these two but can from probability". (pdfs? cdfs? joint? conditional? marginal? something else?) That would likely be covered in the context you chose to omit. What "system" is being discussed?

Comment: For the moment, however, you might benefit from reading a little about copulas (either here or via google search)

Comment: The quotation says correlations and variances. I've edited the question very slightly to be consistent with that. You can revert if you think I really mangled your question.

Comment: @Glen_b I am not sure if I can clear the doubt. For the moment, lets assume that PDFs are given for two variables $x_i$ and $x_o$. The system is with input $x_i$ and output $x_o$; both are random variables.

Comment: Read The Art of Statistics, it will solve most of your doubts. :)
Kind regards, Emma.